# Unable to solve the given equation

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis, physics, code-review

I am trying to solve the given system in terms of $r$, for which I use the following code:

```
    T[rh_, Q_, α_, P_] := (
     8 π P rh^4 + rh^2 - Q^2 - α)/(
     8 π α rh + 4 π rh^3)
    
    M[rh_, Q_, α_, P_] := (
     3 α + 8 π P rh^4 + 3 rh^2 + 3 Q^2)/(6 rh)
    
    S[rh_, α_] := π rh^2 + 
      4 π α Log[rh/Sqrt[Abs[α]]]
    
    ϕ[rh_, Q_] := Q/rh
    
    G[rh_, Q_, α_, P_] := 
    M[rh, Q, α, P] - (T[rh, Q, α, P] S[rh, α])
    f[r_, rh_, Q_, α_, P_] := 
    1 + r^2/(2 α) (1 - Sqrt[
    1 + 4 α ((2 M[rh, Q, α, P])/r^3 - Q^2/r^4 - 1/l^2)])
    Veff[r_] := f[r, rh, Q, α, P] (L^2/r^2 + δ1)
    Block[{δ1 = 0}, Solve[Veff'[r] == 0, r]]
```

I am not getting any answer after waiting for a long time. Is this a Mathematica issue or have I made any errors?

Comment: The functions `T`, `S`, `ϕ`, and `G` are not used and are only noise in this question. Do not include extraneous information.

Comment: Sorry for that, I forgot to delete those while copying the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace your last line with this and it finishes in few seconds

```
Block[{δ1 = 0}, Solve[Simplify[Veff'[r] == 0], r, Reals]]
```

[image]

Comment: If I replace Solve with Reduce, it again keeps on running. Why is that? Shall I give the assumptions for the variables on the top of the code?

Comment: @codebpr good question. I do not know now why Reduces seems to hang but not Solve. May be someone else would know.

Comment: Any known constraints should be included to facilitate solution, assist in simplifications,  and to avoid unnecessarily complicated results.

Comment: @BobHanlon I have some constraints `rh > 0` and `r > rh` but using them in `$Assumptions` didn't help.

Comment: @codebpr - Are any of the other parameters restricted to `Reals`? Mathematica will assume that everything is complex unless told otherwise.

Comment: @BobHanlon yes all of them are `Reals`, I think I should post a new question related to this query!